# What will be the regular expression for pattern like 4,1,66,11,2,77,25,2,99,4,5?

Tags: .net, regex, validation

What will be the regular expression for pattern like 4,1,66,11,2,77,25,2,99,4,5

I am using .NET validation controls.

Comment: Can you explain more generally what your desired pattern should look like?

Comment: Not only that the pattern is unclear, the tool you're trying to use is not meant for generating/validating these kind of series.

Comment: i just want that there should b integer numbers of min 1 and max 4 digit (1,24,2,464,746,12,3488,3)  with comma separating them.

Comment: @MuhammadShariqIqbal How about looking at the regex wikipedia article and then constructing it yourself? It's not that hard, and knowing a bit of regex is often useful.

Comment: Yes from there i made this (\d+,)*(\d+)

Comment: You should include in your question what you've already tried and what didn't work and why it didn't work, otherwise downvoting goes hard ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following (.net) expression matches the entire string: `"(\\d+,)*"`. Using subexpressions you can also match the numbers: `"((\\d+),)*"` (the innermost capture group contains the number).

**Edit:**
Including @metadings solution for completeness:

To match any number of digits between the commas (in the example between 1 and 4) use braces:
`"((\\d{1,4}),)*"`.

Comment: need some modification in this    (\d+,)*(\d+)
It is accepting result with 2324324324,45343224,523434,523434,33424
but i want that number length should not be great then four.

like 232,3,3434,1,53

Comment: @MuhammadShariqIqbal Welcome to StackOverflow. This answer is correct, so please consider to accept it. You have not mentioned the additional requirement in your OP. What you're finally looking for is `((\\d{1,4}),)*`.

Comment: Thank you :) 
and i found my solution with ((\d{1,4}),)*(\d{1,4})

Answer (score 0):

Why you are making two groups with `\d` in your final pattern `((\d{1,4}),)*(\d{1,4})`, try something like this:

```
(\d+,?)
```

or limit the number of digits to capture as:

```
(\d{1,4},?)
```

It will make groups like:

"1," , "4," .... etc

If you want to exclude `,` take it outside the groups, like:

```
(\d+),?
```

OR

```
(\d{1,4}),?
```

Comment: So, the string `1,` should be considered valid?

Comment: @svick, No, thats why the last pattern is suggested. The pattern adopted by the user captures a group along comma as well and it is not documented clearly that if that group is not taken or used with some TRIM function in code.

Comment: because i want end it with digit not with comma that is why i made two groups with \d

Comment: @MuhammadShariqIqbal, so use the last pattern in my answer. It will resolve your issue.